# Not reliable working time of Windows worker

Tags: mining, windows, xmrig

my tiny monero miner ... 64bit 1.9GHz dual CPU with 3GB RAM has some mining issues on the pool.minexmr.com.
I'm using xmrig on Windows 7 Home Premium.

I'm looking for some answers for this
[image]

One worker is working well (that one is running on Ubuntu server), but the Windows worker is a bit lazy time to time.

Both workers are on same network with solid connection. I'm not sure about details, but it is reliable business connection, so there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experimenting with Windows, Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop booted into the command line only.

So my expectations were that Linux will do better than Windows and because of my strong conviction for Linux I was hoping to get maybe a bit higher and constant H/s.

Also, I did same test on a bit worse machine Acer Aspire One 725 (64bit 4GB RAM and 1GHz CPU C-60).
In this case, Windows worked better.

I was able to get 20 - 40 H/s on Windows and Ubuntu Server.
10 H/s in average, according to **minexmr.com** stats.

Ubuntu Desktop booted to CLI wasn't able to get even 1H/s (got 0.4 H/s).
Who said that Ubuntu Server is actual Ubuntu Desktop without DE?
Or is it not?

Large pages are supported, but 4GB not 3GB is not enough to use it.

It would be interesting to know the absolute minimum to get working mining.

Essentially to answer my question, I think that the reason for the issue above is just to weak machine!